# Los enlaces en el chat de SOes apuntan a SO

Tags: soporte, chat

He entrado en el chat de StackOverflow en Español y me he encontrado con esto:

[image: Captura de pantall del chat de SOes]

Hay tres cosas en esa tarjeta que necesitarían arreglarse: (nada en contra de @Gepser :P)

- El texto está en inglés. En general todo en el chat está en inglés, pero parece que eso ocurre en todos los chats de SE (así que quizás es una *prestación* y no un *bug*).
- El icono es el de StackOverflow (en inglés) en lugar de StackOverflow en Español.
- El enlace al perfil de usuario es al del sitio en inglés y no a SOes. Esto sí que es un *bug* porque en los demás chats de SE el perfil apunta al del sitio correspondiente.

Comment: Flechas y círculos hechos a pulso para continuar la ["tradición" de SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/274671)

Comment: reviso esto hoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hay ningún bug. Te explico, cada usuario elije cual sitio mostrar en ese area. Es una propiedad del perfil de usuario en el chat llamada "parent user".

Lo que tienes que hacer para configurar tu "parent user" es.

1. Desde la cualquier sala del chat, clicas "all rooms" (zona sup. derecha)
2. Buscar tu nombre de usuario y lo clicas (en el lugar usual pero sin la puntuación ni el avatar)
3. Cuando estas tu perfil, buscas "parent user", a su lado tiene una opción `[change]`. Al clicarla, aparece una cuadro de búsqueda; allí escribes el nombre (o parte) del sitio que quieras utilizar.
4. Seleccionas el sitio deseado y Listo! Desde aquí en adelante, los demás usuarios, al clicar tu avatar en el chat, verán ese sitio como "sitio principal".

A propósito, hasta donde se, esto es global para todos los canales en la red, por lo que no puedes usar un "parent user" para un canal y otro para otro canal. No estoy seguro de donde sale el valor por defecto, pero puede que se establezca el sitio desde donde has ingresado al chat por primera vez.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]